# Setting up mapping for a JDBC elasticsearch river

Tags: jdbc, mapping, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm using ES 0.20.6 with the [elasticsearch-river-jdbc plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc).
I created a river that works using :

```
SQL="SELECT ..."
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/myindex_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb_db",
        "user" : "myuser",
        "password" : "mypassword",
        "sql" : "'"$SQL"'"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "myindex",
        "type" : "mytype",
        "type_mapping" : null
    }
}'
```

Now what i want is to add type mappings as [the option is defined in the plugin documentation](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/JDBC-River-parameters). But i really cant't figure out the syntax and always get the following error (with the `"Source: "` part varying depending on my attempts)

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Failed to parse mapping definition
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.extractMapping(DocumentMapperParser.java:237)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:147)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:379)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:375)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$4.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:309)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$2.run(InternalClusterService.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
 at [Source: {mytype={properties={active={index_analyzer=standard, store=yes, type=boolean}}}}; line: 1, column: 9]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1378)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:599)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:520)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:616)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.nextToken(JsonXContentParser.java:48)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.XContentMapConverter.readMap(XContentMapConverter.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.XContentMapConverter.readOrderedMap(XContentMapConverter.java:60)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.mapOrdered(AbstractXContentParser.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.extractMapping(DocumentMapperParser.java:235)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are submitting something that is not even a proper json object. I can imagine the type_mapping object has to contain the mapping, pretty much the same mapping that you would submit using the [put mapping api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/) otherwise, or [creating](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-create-index/) the index.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I didn't even thought about it. I was setting up the mapping using continued json notation but i needed to have a json string into my json object... That worked : `"type_mapping" : "{\"mytype\":{\"properties\":{\"active\":{\"type\":\"boolean\",\"store\":\"yes\"}}}}"`. Thanks alot !

Comment: I have to add that I am using Chrome Sense, and it is VERY PARTICULAR about even the carriage return within the json object.

Comment: In ElasticSearch 1.0.0 you should do it like this: http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-configure-jdbc-river-for.html

Comment: i can't get this to work. i've got a similar setup to the above question, however, i can't set a separate mapping at all. it always dynamically maps from the select statement i'm using. what could i be doing wrong?