# Java noclassdeffounderror while running the river plugin for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have successfully installed the elasticsearch and I tried the quick start guide to install the elasticsearch river plugin for jdbc, but when I try to start fetching of a sql table, I keep encountering this error, can someone shed a light on what went wrong? Thanks.

CreationException[Guice creation errors:\n\n1) Error injecting constructor, java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.RiverMouth: Provider org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchTimeoutException\n  at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.JDBCRiver.(Unknown Source)\n  while locating org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.JDBCRiver\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.river.River\n\n1 error]; nested: ServiceConfigurationError[org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.RiverMouth: Provider org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchTimeoutException]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[org/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchTimeoutException]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchTimeoutException];

I suspect its a classpath issue, but then again elasticsearch starts up correctly. Here is the execution path:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp :/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-0.90.10.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/* -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticSearch
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing versions.
The plugin you mentioned is meant to run in a 1.0.0.RC1 elasticsearch node.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer, yes, exactly thats the problem. But now I have another problem, the log shows the bulk inserts, but when I run the _status on the index generated, it does not show the docs are inserted (max_docs only show 1 when there are a few thousand docs).

Comment: Hard to tell without more details. What gives `http://localhost:9200/_search?q=*` ?

Comment: Ok, it did return only 5 rows, instead of about 5000 rows which the log reports, and furthermore, I specify the index as this: "index": {
      "index": "te_places",
      "type": "jdbc"
   }
but instead the results show this: "_index": "jdbc",
            "_type": "jdbc", 
very peculiar indeed.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the _mapping, I am still trying to figure out where type_mapping and the index should appear in, inside the jdbc json object or outside...

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with full details

Comment: i solved the issue, the syntax is very brittle, maybe we need a better tool, the answers are found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012433/setting-up-mapping-for-a-jdbc-elasticsearch-river/16022178#16022178